Managing multiple endpoint fails in a flow
I would like to differentiate between 2 distinct tests within an if function in a flow.
This is my case: I have an endpoint returning a 400 and both of the following tests have failed:
pm.test("Response status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    });

and
pm.test ("Response time is less than 200ms", () => {
    pm.expect (pm. response. responseTime) .to.be.below(200);
    });

However, I only care about the fact that the return was NOT a 200.
How should I put it in this workflow box?
my empty if box

Could you add the tag for the relevant language please?

It's not too clear what you need but here's some info that migth be useful based on what I understand of your question:
You could use a single test with a conditional statement to check if the status code is not 200, it will pass if the status code is not 200 regardless of the actual value:
pm.test("Status code is not 200", function () {
  pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.not.equal(200);
});

If you want to keep two separate tests, you could use a conditional (an if block) to only run the second test if the first test passes:
pm.test("Response status code is 200", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

if (pm.response.code === 200) {
  pm.test("Response time is less than 200ms", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(200);
  });
}

About how to put it in your workflow box, maybe this could help:
IF pm.response.code != 200 THEN 
  pm.test("Status code is not 200", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.not.equal(200);
  })
END IF

